# Send Message to Azure Web Site Instance

Tags: azure, web

we are evaluating Azure right now and I really like the azure web sites, especially because of the very easy and fast deployment, which is helpful in our current situation where we make a lot of tests.

We have some in-memory-caches for information that is accessed very often per request like text-strings for multi-language-support and configuration settings edited by the site administrator. I would like to have a system where each instance of the web site has a copy of this cached data, but i need to send flush-events for cache invalidation to all instances when some settings are changed by the administrator. I guess that the azure service bus is perfect for this with the publish-subscribe-model, but I dont want to pay 3€ per instance just for sending some messages around.

Is there an option to open an individuell endpoint per instance, where I can a wcf-service for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no good way to direct a request at a specific instance of a Windows Azure Web Site that I'm aware of.  The load balancer for Web Sites is defaulted to use sticky sessions (which you can turn off), but there isn't a way to force the request going in to be directed to once instance of a web site over another.

You could look at the Service Bus as you mentioned with a Topic and several subscriptions, which is indeed an option, but as you point out it does cost something. I'm interested in where you got the calculation for the amount though. Brokered messaging is charged per message (with "empty requests also being included").  If you had an instance checking once a minute for a month it's only about 43,000 calls.  You can get 1 million calls for a US Dollar.  With the long polling that Service Bus has in the managed client you end up with fewer "empty" calls than standard polling.

Another option is to simply use a different polling mechanism.  In this case you are just wanting an indicator that you should, or should not flush the cache.  You could put a text file in BLOB storage that contains a cache current version value.  This could be whatever you want, a number, a guid, doesn't matter.  Each instance would then from time to time check this BLOB file.  If the value in the file is different than what they last saw they refresh their cache.  Then they hold on to the new cache version value for their next call.  You can either set this up as a WebJob on a schedule or do your own background polling.

Finally, there is the Windows Azure Cache Service (preview) which is usable by Web Sites, but that would cost additional and, if you really are caching the exact data on all instances, wouldn't be as efficient.  It would give you the ability to deal with the cache service directly though, independent of the instances that are using it, allowing you to reset and such as you needed, on demand, in one fell swoop.

Personally I'd suggest taking a look at the Service Bus again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking about check once per second, which are about 2,5 Mio messages per instance per month = 2.5 €, but this is probably too much, I could reduce it to 10 times a minute or every 10 second, which means 25 Cent (+/-). I will have a closer look to the service bus.

I read something about that there is an option to open individual instances for each instance of a web role, so I had the hope that this is possible for websites as well.

Comment: Btw: Thank you for the tip with long polling, this seems perfect for me.

Comment: There is an InstanceInputEndpoint for cloud services, you are correct.  As far as I know that does not apply to Web Sites.